# Fields populated via @Value in my @Service class become null when accessing that class via @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I've got a Spring Boot application where I am populating fields in a service class by using the @Value annotation:

```
@Value("${test.localDirectory}")
public String localDirectory;
```

I can confirm these are being pulled properly, as I am checking them via ths InitializingBean method:

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    logger.info(localDirectory); //returns expected value here
}
```

However, when I try to access these classes from another spring @Service, they are returning null:

```
@Service
public class AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    private FirstService firstService

    public void example(){
        firstService.localDirectory //returns null
    }

}
```

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Here's a better code example:

```
@Service
public class FirstService{
 
    @Value("${test.localDirectory}")
    public String localDirectory;

}


@Component
public class CommandLineRunnerExecutor implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private FirstService firstService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            logger.info(firstService.localDirectory); //null
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the class where you are using `AnotherService`

Comment: Where are you calling `test`?

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example method. I added better example code. Basically I'm autowiring the service in and trying to reference it in a CommandLineRunner. I'm also accessing it in other services, but this is the first way I've tested it since setting it up.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I get the correct value for `firstService.localDirectory` in `CommandLineRunnerExecutor`. Can you provide a [mre] that shows the issue when run?

Comment: @Unmitigated turns out the autowired service had null fields until I initialized them with the appropriate getter method. ie `firstService.localDirectory` returned null, but `firstService.getLocalDirectory()` returned the correct value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The autowired service had null values that were not being populated until I called the getter. I had been trying to access the public field directly, which resulted in the null value.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

1. Whether you create an instance of `AnotherService` by yourself or Spring injects it for you. If you create it bypassing spring, nothing will be injected and `firstService` instance will be `null`.
2. If its Spring driven - you say that your `FirstService` basically looks like this:

```
@Service
public class FirstService {
   @Value("${test.localDirectory}")
   public String localDirectory;
}
```

Make sure that the instance you obtain in the `AnotherService#test` method is the same instance of the `FirstService` again it might be possible that you mix spring injection and regular creation of object with `new`